# Which analyzer to use on specific strings?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas-search

I have a document in my collection with a property `name` like this:

```
name: [{Value: "steel 0.8x1000x2000mm"}]
```

Now I'm trying to create a search index for it, so far looks like this:

```
...
"name": {
        "fields": {
          "Value": [
            {
              "analyzer": "lucene.finnish",
              "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.finnish",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "dynamic": true,
              "type": "document"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "document"
      },
...
```

And it works pretty fine except for such documents. The issue is that the query `0.8x1000x2000` doesn't match anything, though `0.8x1000x2000mm` works fine.

I guess I'm using the wrong analyzer, but can't really figure out which one should I. Or I should make a custom one?

Comment: It seems you need a custom one with ngram tokenizer, but you know, "it works pretty fine" doesn't say much about implied requirements. You may need multiAnalyzer. The index will explode.